# JavaScript error shows in Joomla1.5 page

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, joomla1.5

I have created the website in Joomla 1.5 CMS link below

http://dev.scopedesign.com/client/nyfarmersmarket_02/

On the page load you can see there is 2 errors like

```
identifier starts immediately after numeric literal [Break On This Error] tweakInitial: {'x': 0, 'y': 10px},
```

I don't know why this error comes and because of this error, order is not working in the page linked below

http://dev.scopedesign.com/client/nyfarmersmarket_02/farmers-market-profiles/markets.html

Kindly guide me how can I overcome this problem...

Comment: No help..:( Please guide me how can i over come this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes around '10px'?

```
tweakInitial: {'x': 0, 'y': 10px},
```